# Django Inner join using ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have the following tables in my sqlite3 database :

```
PRAGMA table_info(auth_user);

0|id|integer|1||1
1|password|varchar(128)|1||0
2|last_login|datetime|0||0
3|is_superuser|bool|1||0
4|username|varchar(150)|1||0
5|first_name|varchar(30)|1||0
6|email|varchar(254)|1||0
7|is_staff|bool|1||0
8|is_active|bool|1||0
9|date_joined|datetime|1||0
10|last_name|varchar(150)|1||0




  PRAGMA table_info(accounts_member);
    0|id|integer|1||1
    1|team_id|integer|1||0
    2|user_id|integer|1||0
    3|department_id|integer|1||0
```

and lastly :

```
PRAGMA table_info(accounts_department);
0|id|integer|1||1
1|name|varchar(20)|1||0
2|description|varchar(255)|1||0
```

The above three tables are related to each other in the  following manner :

`auth_user` is the  main table that links the tables . 
`accounts_member` references auth_user with foreign key user_id and also references `accounts_department` with the  foreign key department_id.

```
    select * from auth_user
 inner join accounts_member on accounts_member.user_id = auth_user.id 
inner join account_department on account_department.department_id = accounts_member.id
```

i have different tutorials but most I get requires use of where function condition.

Below are my models : 
For accounts_department

```
class Department(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "name"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return
```

For accounts_member :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Profile, models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, related_name="memberships")
    department = models.OneToOneField(Department, models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

And table auth_user uses django's inbuilt models.

I tried the  following in my views.py :

```
profile = request.profile
    department = Department.objects.all()
    members = Member.objects.filter(is_active=1).select_related("user","department")
    data  = {
        "page": "profile",
        "profile": profile,
        'departments': department,
        "members_list": members,
        "show_api_keys": False,
        "api_status": "default",
        "team_status": "default"
    }
```

But it only returns the  values of table accounts_member , how do I get all the  values ?

Comment: can you share your model classes please?

Comment: @ruddra , i have updated the  question to include my models and views

Answer (score 0):

Define the tables, and let `cols` be a list of columns.
Then you want something like:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

sess = orm.sessionmaker(engine)()
q = (sess
     .query(*cols)
     .join(accts_member, accts_member.c.user_id == auth_user.c.id)
     .join(acct_dept, acct_dept.c.department_id == accts_member.c.id))
for row in q:
    print(row)
```

I will usually define a table in this way:

```
meta = sa.MetaData(bind=engine)
acct_dept = sa.Table('account_department', meta, autoload=True)
```

Or sometimes I will use [`sqlacodegen`](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/) to generate a class file for a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` to specify the values you want, including those from the related objects. Django will perform the join under the covers.

For example:

```
members = Member.objects.filter(user__is_active=1).values(
    'id',
    'user__id', 
    'user__last_login',
    'user__is_superuser',
    'user__username', 
    'user__firstname',
    'user__email', 
    'user__is_staff',
    'user__date_joined',
    'user__last_name',
    'department__id',
    'department__name',
    'department__description'
)
```